# Are there companies that can store the stream of each user event?

Tags: flash, databases, events

I want a company that can store in a database of it's own the stream of clicks each user does (my game is programmed in action script), of course I will define what data and when to store it. Bear in mind that I am talking about a game that will have millons of users a day.

Comment: This is a really vague question, what data do you exactly want to store, and why, and what do you want todo with it once it has been stored. There is no such thing as an automatic-service that does everthing for you.  Why can't you just log your inputs events in memory and at the end of each game insert them into a database yourself (I'm thinking of a table like |ID|event|eventArgs|gameState|SessionID|)

Comment: and expecting millions of users a day with such a vague idea seems overly optimistic to say the least.

Comment: this question does not sound right. Are you sure you mean companies?

Comment: -1; I agree with Roy T.

Comment: As this question has now collected a couple answers which seem to reflect popular opinion, and has also accumulated some downvotes and close votes, I am closing it. @mariana, please read and reflect on the information gathered here, and if you need help implemented specific aspects, feel free to ask other questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean you want a library or application. Not a company; that is, a business.

And you are being seriously over-optimistic. Even World Of Warcraft will not reach 1 million unique users a day.

As for the technical aspect, you're going to need:

- Some server to host the database. Expect to pay a lot for some 30 million people a month using it.
- Some database to host on the server. I would look up SQL databases.
- Flash access to said database, sending the user and their 'stream of clicks'. Each time they click.

Answer (score 0):

There are companies out there that can host a database, sure, but you'll have to be the one to design the database and then collect and store the data.  You will have to implement that kind of collection into your game.